# Is there a way to disable budget optimization through the Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

Unfortunately, I couldn't find information in Facebook's documentation about creating a campaign where budget optimization is disabled. There is a switch for optimization in the cabinet for business, but is it possible to do it through the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no field that matches directly to this switch at cabinet for business.

But yes, it is possible. If you want campaign budget optimization to be disabled you should set `daily_budget` or `lifetime_budget` at the adset level instead of campaign level.